# How to change the image type of a BufferedImage which is loaded from file?

Tags: java, type-conversion, bufferedimage, javax.imageio

I'm trying to access the pixels in a `BufferedImage` which is loaded from a file using `ImageIO.read(filePath)`, but I get **this error**:

```
Exception in thread "Game" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.awt.image.DataBufferByte cannot be cast to java.awt.image.DataBufferInt
    at com.package.graphics.Texture.<init>(Texture.java:29)
    at com.package.graphics.Texture.loadTexture(Texture.java:40)
    at com.package.Game.run(Game.java:71)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

In the code, the line which the error is on, is in the constructor and looks like this:

```
// Get the pixel array from the BufferedImage
this.pixels = ((DataBufferInt) image.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
```

As I understand this, the BufferedImage isn't of the type `BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB` or `BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB`. Because I use these types in the rest of my game, I wonder if there is a way to 'convert' the loaded image from the type it was loaded as, to another.
In my case, I want to convert the image type to `BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Create a new Buffered image with the type you want

```
BufferedImage in = ImageIO.read(img);
BufferedImage newImage = new BufferedImage(in.getWidth(), in.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

Graphics2D g = newImage.createGraphics();
g.drawImage(in, 0, 0, in.getWidth(), in.getHeight(), null);
g.dispose();
```

Comment: Okay, thanks! But you have to draw the old image on the new too.

Comment: I'll add that to your answer.

Comment: Fixed the code to only invoke `createGraphics()` once (`getGraphics()` invokes the same).

Answer (score 7):

A slightly (ok, I admit, quite a bit) more verbose, but in most cases faster and more memory efficient way of doing the same, is to load the image directly into a `TYPE_INT_ARGB` image.

If your images are large, you'll benefit quite a bit from doing it this way, over first loading into a `byte` type. If your images are small, it might not be worth the extra code complexity, as you'll hardly notice the difference.

Anyway, you can do it like this:

```
// Create input stream
try (ImageInputStream input = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(file)) {
    // Get the reader
    Iterator<ImageReader> readers = ImageIO.getImageReaders(input);

    if (!readers.hasNext()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("No reader for: " + file); // Or simply return null
    }

    ImageReader reader = readers.next();

    try {
        // Set input
        reader.setInput(input);

        // Configure the param to use the destination type you want
        ImageReadParam param = reader.getDefaultReadParam();
        param.setDestinationType(ImageTypeSpecifier.createFromBufferedImageType(BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB));

        // Finally read the image, using settings from param
        BufferedImage image = reader.read(0, param);
    }
    finally {
        // Dispose reader in finally block to avoid memory leaks
        reader.dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! My images are pretty small (About 32x32 pixels), so I won't use this code, but I'll upvote it.

/TheDDestroyer12

Comment: Thank a lot! But, for jpeg images, setDestinationType doesn't work (with integrated ICC profile). param.setDestination(new BufferedImage(reader.getWidth(0), reader.getHeight(0), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB)); do the job ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You're telling the JVM that `image.getRaster().getDataBuffer()` returns a DataBufferInt when it actually returns a DataBufferByte. That's a ClassCastException. You need to cast the return value to the correct type.

```
// Get the pixel array from the BufferedImage
this.pixels = ((DataBufferByte) image.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
```

Comment: Yes, but if you read the whole question, you see that I mention that I wan't the image to be of the type `BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB`, because all of my other `BufferedImage`s is of that type, and I solved that problem by doing as @overflowed suggested. Thanks anyways.