# Is closing ImageInputStream enough, if I do not use readers directly?

Tags: java, resources, try-catch, javax.imageio

I read BufferedImage from Internet Connection, using ImageIntputStream. I close ImageIntputStream creating it in the try header.

```
try(ImageIntputStream is = new ImageIntputStream(connection)) {
    BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(is);
} catch(IOException readException) {
    readException.printStackTrace();
}
```

I thought, it is enough for safety. But reading posts about work with readers/writers, such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31111762/writer-dispose-not-working-as-intended) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27457517/how-to-change-the-image-type-of-a-bufferedimage-which-is-loaded-from-file) or [here](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?class=javax.imageio.ImageIO&method=createImageOutputStream), I see, that I should flush something, dispose of something, close something, and put null to something, and these things are sometimes different, If I use reader separately. Seeing such insistent destroying of the reader and stream or anything that is connected to them, I feel ashamed of my weak and primitive measures for safety.

If I do not use this ImageReader, what else have I to flush, dispose, null, close, shut down, shoot, kill, annihilate, degrade, silence, maim or offend in some other way after I got my image?

Answer (score 2):

> I feel ashamed of my weak and primitive measures for safety.

TLDR;

**Don't be. You are good.**

---

Long version:

You are using the [*try-with-resources* statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html), that automatically invokes `close()` on the resource in an "implicit" `finally` after the `try` is done. The `ImageInputStream` is the only resource *you* create, thus it's the only resource that is your responsibility to dispose of.

The `ImageIO.read` method will handle internal housekeeping, like disposing the `ImageReader` instances etc. itself. This is not your responsibility (you don't even have access to these objects, so you couldn't even if you really wanted to).

To release the memory of the returned `BufferedImage` it's enough to just assign the `null` reference or let it pass out of scope. The garbage collector will clean things up for you, as with any normal Java object. You *may* also invoke `flush()` to release native/display memory associated with the image, if any. It doesn't hurt. If you don't, the memory will be freed anyway, so don't worry.

---

Longer version:

The posts you refer to in your question, is mostly unrelated to your code. Two of them are about *writing* images, using an `ImageWriter` directly. In this case, you should always `close()` the `ImageOutputStream` and `dispose()` the `ImageWriter` instance after use.

The last (ok, the middle one) of the posts you refer to, is about *drawing* to a `BufferedImage` using a `Graphics` context. In this case, you should always `dispose()` the `Graphics/Graphics2D` after use.

It is also possible to read images using an `ImageReader` directly (similar to the writing examples). In this case, you should always `close()` the `ImageInputStream` and `dispose()` the `ImageReader` instance.

These are, however, different use cases from what you are doing in the code sample in the question. I'm just adding it here for completeness.

Finally, a word of advice: Don't let yourself be confused by reading random Google results. If in doubt, go to the source. Either literally, by reading the Java libraries source code, or read the API doc. ;-)

---

Further reading:

- Java2D tutorial, [Lesson: Working with Images](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/index.html)
- [ImageIO.read API doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#read(javax.imageio.stream.ImageInputStream))
- [BufferedImage API doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html)
- [Image.flush API doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Image.html#flush())

Comment: ImageIntputStream does not know about any resources, used by ImageIO.read(), and cannot close them. So, we should count on ImageIO.read() closing just after the operation. But then it does not look as a stream reading...

Comment: I think, I simply must call the operation for thousand times and check for memory leak.

Comment: The problem is that heap of example code that is organized in much more complex way. And they insist that all these additional flush/dispose/ different closes/nulls are necessary. So, I will simply check it... And in the project I have many similar, but not the same pieces of code, so, I have to check them, too. Or simply read the code of the libraries. These implementations of ImageStream are all different.

Comment: The stream reading I understand as some sort of lazy reading, that in reality could be postponed or not finished at once, and the act of stream reading simply cannot be STANDARDLY finished and closed at once.

Comment: @Gangnus I'm afraid you have completely misunderstood the concept then... A `BufferedImage` is basically just an in-memory representation of pixel data. It is created up-front, and filled with data from a file/stream during `ImageIO.read`. Once `ImageIO.read` is done, you no longer need the file/stream again (thus you can close it, like you do in the implicit `finally` block of the "try-with-resources"). *There's no lazy fetching of data in any way.*

Comment: (While we are two here, no need in naming) So, only the need of flushing the Buffered image after using it remains? And what will you say about the post of Stephen?

Comment: @Gangnus There's usually no need to `flush()` a `BufferedImage`. Just assign `null` or let it pass out of scope, and it will be happily garbage collected like any other Java object. The `flush()` method is there because `BufferedImage` inherits `Image`, for historical reasons. It *may*  free up native/video memory for accelerated images (ie. may matter if you create a game or 3D engine or so). It will not free any heap memory.

Comment: Veeery interesting. It is a pity that it is not in the answer. There is another type of memory in Java apart from stack and heap? Could you give some reference about that, for I feel ashamed to use you so.

Comment: I didn't mention it in the answer, as I didn't think it is relevant in relation to your question. But I'll add some furter reading pointers. Most of it is in the API doc though...

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to flush any reader or whatever that wraps an input stream.  Flushing is for output.

However, closing the reader is safe, and (IMO) clean.  And it does guard against the *hypothetical* possibility that some releasable resources are held at the reader level; e.g. if you or someone else had reason to change your application to use a different reader class.

For example, a `FileCacheImageInputStream` will cache the input stream in a temporary file.  The cache file is only deleted when the `FileCacheImageInputStream` is closed.  So in *that* case, just closing the base stream may leak files and/or file descriptors.

Comment: So, instead of using read directly from the InputSream, I should create a reader and read from it and close reader and the stream after reading? Could you put a/some reference(s) to code that is correct, according to you? On the discussed theme, of course. For I am afraid, I will miss some of these flushing, disposing, closing and nulling. I am asking about reading only, but the project uses writing too, of course.

Comment: Really, I am frightened. I thought, the closing of the stream will automatically include flushing, disposing and closing of the used readers/writers...

Comment: I have no idea how you made the logical leap from what I said to any of that.  Just close the `ImageInputStream` and the socket / connection (if appropriate) and  you will be fine.

Comment: Closing an **output** stream **from the outermoster wrapper** takes care of buffer flushing.  But for an **input** stream, no buffer flushing is necessary.   But, hey, don't **worry** about it.  Go and read the javadocs (carefully) and understand what happens for yourself.

Comment: @StephenC Actually, the JRE-bundled `JPEGImageReader` uses libjpeg though JNI. There's a reference from the Java code to a native allocated struct. This is not just hypothetical. There are guards in place that will deallocate the native memory on object finalization. But as it's hard to determine when finalization happens, just invoking `dispose()` is still good practice. All this is probably besides the point though, as this *is already handled* inside `ImageIO.read`.